# How to evaluate a .pb model (for object detection) created with TensorFlow API?

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers, object-detection-api, tfrecord, precision-recall

I can't figure out how I can evaluate error metrics for the model I have **already trained**, taking advantage of protbuf and the tensorflow API.

The main problem is that the model is saved as `.pb` but in the zipper file I download I also have assets, variable. So to test it for example, I upload the zipper to colab and unzip it.

Then I use an infernce.py , exploiting the labelmap.pbtxt and giving the model path of the unzipped folder.

```
!python /content/inference.py -m /content/content/inference_graph/saved_model -l /content/testlabel_map.pbtxt -i /content/models/research/object_detection/test_images/my_test_folder
```

How do I calculate precision, recall, mAP?
Could I also do this with Tensorboard? If so how?

I usually use the model.evaluate function, this is the first time I have done such work using protobuf, TFRrecords and tensorflow. I have no idea how I can manage to calculate the error metrics of my model.